# Remove all characters that are not letters or numbers in a String

Tags: javascript, regex, string

how can i remove all characters that are not letters or 'numbers'??

I have a string:

```
var string = 'This - is my 4 String, and i - want remove all characters 49494 that are not letters or "numbers"';
```

And i want transform into this:

```
var string = 'This is my 4 String and i want remove all characters 49494 that are not letters or numbers'
```

This is possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: `string.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '')`

Comment: you want write just numbers in text and or numbers and letters only? or after they write you remove them?

Comment: numbers and letters only @MohammedMoustafa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
[\W_]+
```

The idea is to match with `\W` a non word character (those characters that are not `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` and `_`) and also add explicitly `_` (since underscore is considered a word character)

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/pP9vM1/1)**

```
var str = 's - is my 4 String, and i - want remove all characters 49494 that are not letters or "numbers"';     
var result = str.replace(/[\W_]+/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

The way **I like to do it** is using a RegEx. This will select all **non**-letters and **non**-numbers and replace them with nothing or deleting them:

```
string = string.replace(/[^\s\dA-Z]/gi, '').replace(/ +/g, ' ');
```

Explanantion:

```
[^  NOT any of there
  \s  space
  \d  digit
  A-Z letter
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible using regular expressions

```
string = string.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+|\s+/gmi, " ");
```

Comment: could you explain? :B